# Make slides with same number

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-office-2019

Suppose I have two slides, one says "hello" and the other adds "world". I want both slides to be the same **slide number**.

One way to do that is with animation,so that "world" would appear on the same slide. Is there a way to group to separate slides so that they will always be of the same slide number?

Specifically, I'm using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019.

Comment: When it comes to slide numbers, do you simply want the APPEARANCE of them having the same slide number, i.e. are we looking for a way to change the slide number in the footer of your page, or do you want them to REALLY be on the same slide number (i.e. the "Slide 1 of 5" in the bottom left corner of powerpoint application.

Comment: I would rather have the latter but can live with the former :) @MoragHughson

Answer (score 1):

I have used [PPspliT](http://www.maxonthenet.altervista.org/ppsplit.php) for that in the past because I wanted to export presentations to PDF without loosing information from animations. However I don't know if it works with the current office version.